# do web browsers cache redirect responses? Or laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, https

So I had built a little URL shortener with Laravel 5.4 where I have a route that does: domain.com/{urlkey}  -  I grab the key and look it up in my Laravel cache which is in Redis. I also have another key that tracks the # of visits - so anytime the URL is accessed i Just increment the :visits key.

Now I have been noticing when i take one of these URLs copy and paste it into a new tab... or even click it from my application it just ignores my code completely. I can put in a die() and it wont even stop! which will never trigger the cache increment on the key...

Any ideas what is going on? Probably missing something very obvious.

The simple lookup and increment is below: but I dont even think it is hitting the code? Why would this be?

Other note the domain is https - however I have tested this on both http and https

```
    // retrieve redirect URL from cache
    $redirectUrl = Cache::get('short:' . $shortKey);

    // if we find the redirect in the cache - increment visits - 301 redirect
    if($redirectUrl)
    {
        Cache::increment('short:' . $shortKey . ':visits', 1);

        return redirect($redirectUrl, 301);
    }
```

Comment: Chrome will cache a 301 for sure.  You can prove it to yourself by running Fiddler and observing the browser being redirected to the destination page without any HTTP traffic flowing through the proxy.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it will not cache a 302.

Comment: so how do companies like bit.ly track clicks if web browers are caching the 301 redirect response?

Comment: what i ended up doing was adding cache-control header of no-cache and set the expires header to an old date. seems to be working fine now. and able to stay as a 301

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because 301 = Moved Permanently, the browser will cache it and redirect automatically next time without calling the original page

If I am not mistaking, if you want the redirect to always go thru the original page, you need to replace the 301 with a `302 Found`

Comment: Aw ok. Let me try that out.